# how to check if sqldatareader return any value

Tags: c#, null, sqldatareader

Here is the code i came up with::

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.Read())
    intQ = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
else
    intQ = 0;

txtblck.Text = intQ.ToString();
reader.Close();
```

But this causes it to always execute the else, and if i do this:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
    intQ = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
else
    intQ = 0;

txtblck.Text = intQ.ToString();
reader.Close();
```

The if always return true, how should do this?

Comment: Obviously the resultset doesn't contain what you expect... What query are you using to get the data from the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reader.Read()` advances the reader to the next record, where the reader is initially set to before the first record.  If calling `reader.Read()` returns false this means that it was unable to advance to the next record (i.e. the current record is the last record).

This means that if you wish to read the first record you need to call `reader.Read()` once, and if `reader.Read()` returns false it means there were no records - like so:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        intQ = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        intQ = 0;
    }
}
txtblck.Text = intQ.ToString();
```

FYI `int.Parse` will throw an exception if the first record is null - this is different from having zero rows.  Perhaps you should check for null values, or use `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: but if i use it once, it would always return true,

Comment: @dreamer If you always have at least 1 record then yes, it will always return `true`.

Comment: yea, but when it execute the next line, it thrown an exception because of incorrect data

Comment: @dreamer FYI If the first record isn't an integer (for example if it is `null`) then the `int.Parse` will throw an error - perhaps you should check for null values, or use `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: i thought it checks for null before it execute the parse? so how do i check if it return a null value?

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct way of checking if there is a record in the set or not. If the `Read` method always returns true, it means that you always have at least one record. If that record doesn't contain what you expect, you have to find out what's returned from the database in order to figure out how to determine if you should use it or not.

Comment: @Guffa, well, it is supposed to return an integer, but there are some cases where it doesnt, here is the sql query string:

` "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM rec_stats WHERE material=0 AND (date_in BETWEEN '" + startDate.SelectedDate + "' AND '" + endDate.SelectedDate + "' )" `

the startdate and the endate is a datepicker, so it will search for record between those dates. and of course there are some cases where there is no record between those dates... and that is what i want to deal with..

Comment: @dreamer: in case you get no data back, then the value returned would be `NULL`, and you could find out about that by checking `if(reader.IsDBNull(0)) .....` to check for `NULL`. Your data reader will have a result - but it's really `NULL`

Comment: @dreamer: The query will always return one row, and the value will be null if the condition doesn't match any records in the table. You can either check for that null value, or you can turn it into a zero in the query using `isnull(sum(amount), 0)`.

Answer (score 9):

Check the [HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx) property.  Perhaps this is what you're looking for (your question is quite clear to me).

```
if( reader.HasRows )
```

HasRows returns a value if the resultset contains records.
Do you want to achieve that ?
Or, do you want to know whether a particular field of a certain record contains a value ?

How does your SQL Statement look like ?

Comment: i thought of that too, but i dont know why, it always return true, and because it would execute intQ = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
when there is no data, it always throw an exception

Comment: @dreamer Are you sure the value of your data isn't `NULL`? Consider using int.TryParse() rather than int.Parse().

Comment: Your answer seems good for what he actually intends to ask, but somehow couldn't clear it. However there is minor correction, HasRows is a property in SqlDataReader Class and hence can not be directly used on the object returned by the ExecuteReader() function.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the [the MSDN documentation for `SqlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) reveals that is has a property called `HasRows` which you can use.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read() gets the next row of the result set.

So if you return one row the first read gets that row and the second  Read() returns false as there is no second row - so the else happens.

Comment: but if i use it once, it would always return true,